# Azure Web App Mutual SSL authentication with client certificate in Azure App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, ssl-certificate, mutual-authentication

I'm trying to set up mutual SSL authentication in an Azure Web App using a custom client certificate. I've configured the Azure Web App by switching the "Client certificate mode" to "Required" in the settings. However, when accessing the application, Azure provides a certificate instead of using our custom client certificate. We prefer not to utilize API Management and want to achieve this directly within the App Service.

Is there a way to configure the Azure Web App to accept our specific client certificate for mutual SSL authentication without going through API Management? Any guidance or steps on how to accomplish this within the App Service settings would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After enabling the `client certificate mode` to `require` add setting `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES = *` to load all certificates or `thumbprint` of the certificate in `Enviroment variables`.

[image]

[image]

**For reference check this [doc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/).**

**`OUTPUT`:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: yes its working like a magic